# How Allocate PDF File As Email Attachment

Tags: cordova

Would like to know what is a best way to send pdf file as email attachment in phonegap?

What is a best suitable plugin that can be used on Android, ios , and blackberry

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this cordova/phonegap plugin:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

Just attach the PDF as base64-String.
Works great in most cases!

If you want to create a pdf, use jsPDF:
http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

Easy to use!